# How to mock Amazon S3 Client for a .NET unit test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, amazon-s3, moq

I note that the important members of `AmazonS3Client` are *virtual*, so a `Mock<AmazonS3Client>` should be easy. But

```
new Mock<AmazonS3Client>()
```

using Moq, got me an error saying that there was no valid `RegionEndpoint`.

So obviously a little more is required.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of tightly coupling the code to implementation concerns, take note that [`AmazonS3Client`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client.htm) class implements [`IAmazonS3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TIS3.html) (v2,v3) or [`AmazonS3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3.htm) (v1) interface according to referenced AWS SDK for .NET Documentation.

```
public class AmazonS3Client : IAmazonS3, IDisposable {
    //...
}
```

I would suggest you have your code depend on the abstraction (*interface*) and not on the implementation (*class*).

```
public class MyClass {
    private readonly IAmazonS3 client;

    public MyClass(IAmazonS3 client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    //...
}
```

That would then allow greater flexibility when swapping dependencies with mocks when testing in isolation.

You have already experienced that added dependencies needed to mock the implementation of `AmazonS3Client` which can be avoided if the interface is used as the dependency.

```
s3ClientMock = new Mock<IAmazonS3>();
```

The `Setup` of the mocked interface can be done as you would normally as already demonstrated in your answer.

In production the properly configured implementation can be injected into dependent classes.

Comment: Or even better - introduce own interface which will wrap required functionality to methods you actually need. Which protect main code base from possible changes Amazon interface will have in the future.

Comment: So it does. Now I'm embarrassed I missed it and am torn between accepting your answer and just deleting the question.

Comment: @Fabio -- why do you think that's better? More code is worse.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll it is a valid point. It allows your API to be less fragile to changes made by Amazon to their SDK. As demonstrated by the update you had to make to my answer to take the new SDK versions into consideration.

Comment: In most codebases, I think not, because if the SDK changes, your adapter code will likely change in step. My experience of people writing adapters is that it rarely improves a decent API (which someone at least thought about long enough to publish) ; and they often adapt towards specific requirements at the time they adapt. Which sometimes – not always – results in adapted adapted code when requirements evolve. So personally I would take the rule of thumb "less is better" before going with "the API might be fragile"

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll you point is also very valid. I would say do what works best for you.

Answer (score 16):

Using `Moq`, adding these constructor args seemed to work okay:

```
s3ClientMock= new Mock<AmazonS3Client>(
    FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(true), 
    new AmazonS3Config{RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1});
```

And I can then set up as normal:

```
Stream GivenDocInS3Bucket(string pathToTestDoc)
{
  var docStream = new FileInfo(pathToTestDoc).OpenRead();

  s3ClientMock
    .Setup(x => x.GetObjectAsync(
       It.IsAny<string>(), 
       It.IsAny<string>(), 
       It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(
       (string bucket, string key, CancellationToken ct) =>
         new GetObjectResponse
         {
           BucketName = bucket,
           Key = key,
           HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
           ResponseStream = docStream,
         });

  return docStream;
}
```

But as [Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544951/how-to-mock-amazon-s3-client-for-a-net-unit-test#49546748) points out, I didn't need the constructor; I had simply overlooked the existence of the `IAmazonS3` interface.