# Mocking AmazonS3Client with C# using Moq

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, nunit, moq

Im trying to make unit test for a class that uses Amazon S3 client and I want to mock the client.

When creating the Mock I receive a System.ArgumentException. Here's my code

```
public class AmazonAnalysisTests
{
    private AmazonConfig _config;
    private AmazonAnalysis _amazonAnalysis;
    private Mock<IAmazonS3> _mockS3Client;


    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _config = new AmazonConfig
        {
            AccessKeyId = "access_key",
            SecretAccessKey = "secret_key",
            Region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
            BucketName = "test-bucket",
            RoleArn = "role_arn",
            SnsTopicArn = "sns_topic_arn",
            Url = "sqs_url"
        };

        _mockS3Client = new Mock<IAmazonS3>();

        _amazonAnalysis = new AmazonAnalysis(_mockS3Client.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void PutDocumentOnS3Bucket_UpdatesRecordStatus()
    {
        _mockS3Client.Setup(c => c.PutObject(It.IsAny<PutObjectRequest>()))
            .Returns(new PutObjectResponse { HttpStatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK });

        _amazonAnalysis.PutDocumentOnS3Bucket();

        // Assert
        _mockS3Client.Verify(client => client.PutObject(It.IsAny<PutObjectRequest>()), Times.Exactly(1));

    }
```

When I try the above code, I get this error.

`System.ArgumentException : 'Null is not a valid constant value for this type.`
`Cette exception a été levée à l'origine dans cette pile des appels :      System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.SetConstantValue(System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder, int, System.Type, object)`

Comment: Error indicates you got a null results.  Which line of code?  One reason is the connection did not complete which can be caused by lots of reasons.

Comment: @jdweng error appens when executing line 

_amazonAnalysis = new AmazonAnalysis(_mockS3Client.Object);

it cannot event created the mocked object

Comment: You client does not have any properties : 'new Mock<IAmazonS3>();".   See answer 2 at following to add properties : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544951/how-to-mock-amazon-s3-client-for-a-net-unit-test?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

I found a "strange" solution. Visual Studio seams to throw an exception but it dont stop the excecution. If you desactivate this exception and continue the execution, the Mock will work as normal.